# Java sublime.build works in one directory but not in another

Tags: java, sublimetext3

I want to ask a question about a sublime build configuration file.

I wrote the following sublime-build file to run Java files:

```
{
"shell_cmd": "javac $file && java $file_base_name"
}
```

and when I run the following file in the directory

```
"/Users/(user)/Desktop/Java/Setup/HelloApp.java"
```

it works.

[image: Screenshot showing standard build]

However, when I run my first tutorial files in the directory

```
"/Users/(user)/Desktop/Java/Book 1/Chapter 1"
```

my files `greeter.java` and `helloApp2.java` do not work and give the following error:

```
javac: invalid flag: /Users/(user)/Desktop/Java/Book
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 2]
[shell_cmd: javac /Users/(user)/Desktop/Java/Book 1/Chapter 1/HelloApp2.java && java HelloApp2]
[dir: /Users/(user)/Desktop/Java/Book 1/Chapter 1]
[path: /Users/(user)/anaconda3/bin:/Users/(user)/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public]
```

I thought that the sublime-build file should work as normal as per my above example.

This is `HelloApp2.java`:

```
public class HelloApp2 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Greeter myGreeterObject = new Greeter();
        myGreeterObject.sayHello();
    }
}
```

and this is `Greeter.java`:

```
public class Greeter {
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For some absolutely bizarre reason, spaces are not acceptable in the file directory of a sublime shell.

By this I mean:

```
"/Users/(user)/Desktop/Java/Book 1/Chapter 1"
```

is unacceptable whereas changing the folder names to

```
"/Users/(user)/Desktop/Java/Book1/Chapter1"
```

appears to work.

**UPDATE**

I changed the sublime-build file to include escape quotes:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file\" && java \"$file_base_name\""
}
```

I'm not too sure how this works, so any explanations would be accepted!